# Windows Protector adware removal in Mac

Tags: macos, mac

I am getting frequently adware prompt from windows-protector.com when I visit sites in Safari. I formatted my Mac and installed a fresh copy of the OS from a bootable USB drive but still, I am getting adware prompts.

I am worried my Mac is compromised, any suggestions on how can I get rid of this adware? Malware bytes report comes clean

[image: screenshot]

Comment: windows-protector.com leads to a "404 Not Found" page.

Comment: Have you tried using the mac with another network?

Comment: Also, did you restore any user data backup after reinstalling?